# Video Stabilization

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, video-processing, image-stabilization

I 'm researching about Video Stabilization field. I implement a application using OpenCV.

My progress such as:

Surf points extraction

Matching

estimateRigidTransform

warpAffine

But the result video is not be stable. Can anyone  help me this problem or provide me some source code link to improve?

Sample video: [Hippo video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/b29htm5x37sbc87/test12.avi?dl=0)

Here is my code [EDIT]

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

const double smooth_level = 0.7;
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
struct TransformParam
{
    TransformParam() {}
    TransformParam(double _dx, double _dy, double _da) {
    dx = _dx;
    dy = _dy;
    da = _da;
}
   double dx; // translation x
   double dy; // translation y
   double da; // angle
};
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
     VideoCapture cap ("test12.avi");  
     Mat cur, cur_grey;
     Mat prev, prev_grey;


     cap >> prev;
     cvtColor(prev, prev_grey, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

     // Step 1 - Get previous to current frame transformation (dx, dy, da) for all frames
     vector <TransformParam> prev_to_cur_transform; // previous to current

     int k=1;
     int max_frames =  cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);
     VideoWriter writeVideo ("stable.avi",0,30,cvSize(prev.cols,prev.rows),true);
     Mat last_T;
     double avg_dx = 0, avg_dy = 0, avg_da = 0;
     Mat smooth_T(2,3,CV_64F);
     while(true) {
        cap >> cur;

        if(cur.data == NULL) {
           break;
        }

        cvtColor(cur, cur_grey, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

        // vector from prev to cur
        vector <Point2f> prev_corner, cur_corner;
        vector <Point2f> prev_corner2, cur_corner2;
        vector <uchar> status;
        vector <float> err;

        goodFeaturesToTrack(prev_grey, prev_corner, 200, 0.01, 30);
        calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(prev_grey, cur_grey, prev_corner, cur_corner, status, err);

       // weed out bad matches
       for(size_t i=0; i < status.size(); i++) {
           if(status[i]) {
               prev_corner2.push_back(prev_corner[i]);
              cur_corner2.push_back(cur_corner[i]);
           }
       }

       // translation + rotation only
       Mat T = estimateRigidTransform(prev_corner2, cur_corner2, false); 

       // in rare cases no transform is found. We'll just use the last known good transform.
       if(T.data == NULL) {
          last_T.copyTo(T);
       }

       T.copyTo(last_T);

      // decompose T
      double dx = T.at<double>(0,2);
      double dy = T.at<double>(1,2);
      double da = atan2(T.at<double>(1,0), T.at<double>(0,0));
      prev_to_cur_transform.push_back(TransformParam(dx, dy, da));

      avg_dx = (avg_dx * smooth_level) + (dx * (1- smooth_level));
      avg_dy = (avg_dy * smooth_level) + (dy * (1- smooth_level));
      avg_da = (avg_da * smooth_level) + (da * (1- smooth_level));

      smooth_T.at<double>(0,0) = cos(avg_da);
      smooth_T.at<double>(0,1) = -sin(avg_da);
      smooth_T.at<double>(1,0) = sin(avg_da);
      smooth_T.at<double>(1,1) = cos(avg_da);

      smooth_T.at<double>(0,2) = avg_dx;
      smooth_T.at<double>(1,2) = avg_dy;

      Mat stable;
      warpAffine(prev,stable,smooth_T,prev.size());

      Mat canvas = Mat::zeros(cur.rows, cur.cols*2+10, cur.type());
      prev.copyTo(canvas(Range::all(), Range(0, prev.cols)));
      stable.copyTo(canvas(Range::all(), Range(prev.cols+10, prev.cols*2+10)));

      imshow("before and after", canvas);
      waitKey(20);
      writeVideo.write(stable);
      cur.copyTo(prev);
      cur_grey.copyTo(prev_grey);
      k++;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can just blur you image. It will helps a bit. Second, you can easily smooth your matrix by simplest implementation of exponential smooth A(t+1) = a*A(t)+(1-a)*A(t+1) and play with a-value in [0;1] range.  Third, you can turn off some type of transformations like rotation, shift etc.
Here is code example:

```
t = estimateRigidTransform(new, old, 0); // 0 means not all transformations (5 of 6)
if(!t.empty()){
//  t(Range(0,2), Range(0,2)) = Mat::eye(2, 2, CV_64FC1); // turning off rotation
//  t.at<double>(0,2) = 0; t.at<double>(1,2) = 0; // turning off shift dx and dy
    tAvrg = tAvrg*a + t*(1-a); // a - smooth level in [0;1] range, play with it
    warpAffine(new, stable, tAvrg, Size(new.cols, new.rows));
}
```

Comment: How to control smooth level in [0,1]

Comment: 1. tAvrg is averaged(smoothed) t , where t is transformation matrix.  2. Rotation is not turned off, this line is commented to allow you uncomment it and turn rotation off if it is meet your case. 3. Just use different values for a and check result.

Comment: I changed my code as your advice. But the result is not stable. Could you help me to show the problem, please?

Comment: What kind of instability do you have?

Comment: The result seem like as the original video. Here is the result:https://www.dropbox.com/s/56rx4wtzbzpb5gd/stable.avi?dl=0

Comment: Try different values of a: 0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.5, 0.9, 0.95, 1

Comment: I tried different values as you asked, but the video is not stable. Did you read my above code? I dont know whether I did something wrong.

Comment: It seems you add new code since my first answer.As I can see now your have another problem:you do exponential smoothing but you do it wrong --it is high pass filter while you need low pass filter.So you should use "warpAffine(prev,stable,smooth_T-T,prev.size());". I mean "smooth_T-T", not just "smooth_T". By changing smooth_level you can change stability of your image, 0.7 may be not the best value.
Or you can take correct version of "your" code here (there is no exponential smoothing but you can change averaging method if you want): http://nghiaho.com/uploads/code/videostab.cpp

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I read that code for a long time ago, but I want to try the exponential method. Your meant 'smooth_T-T" is difference between smooth_T and T, isn't it?

Comment: Yes it is difference like "5-3=2". You'd better use that code but just change its average smoothing ("avg_a = sum_a / count;" etc.) to exponential smoothing (gauss smoothing or any type of low-pass filter you want), and don't forget you need high-pass for your transformation (approximately: low-pass = signal - high-pass , that is where difference comes from) "diff_x = smoothed_trajectory[i].x - x;". May be drawing charts for x, y, a, diff_x, diff_y, diff_a and dx, dy, da will clarify to you the idea of this method.

Comment: One more question: you said that I need high pass for my transformation, so diff_x is low pass, isn't it?. And "diff_x = smoothed_trajectory[i]. x - x". In this line, x is trajectory of x. So you asked me that drawing their charts. So what do you mean "x is original_x or trajectory_x"? Sorry if I ask silly question.

Comment: And smoothed_trajectory is signal, x is high pass?

Comment: Just change smoothing method ("Step 3") for avg_a, avg_x and avg_y to exponential smoothing. No more. That code is correct with any type of smoothing. And I have already told you where is the error in your code. Dig in to it, don't be harry.